# Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a grid that loads and returns JSON items. A radio button filter has been added to filter those items. Every time the radio button is selected, the grid items will be refreshed to display items that fit the filtering criteria.

THe thing is, when I click the radio button, nothing happens and I see a `Cannot read property '0' of undefined` error. The JSON loads correctly and there aren't any 404 or 500 errors, which I can confirm using Chrome DevTools. The offending line of code appears to be `while (typeof n.main[l.toString()] != "undefined")`. Below is the function containing said code:

```
function j(n) {
var m = [],
    l;
if (n.main != "undefined") {
    l = 0;
    while (typeof n.main[l.toString()] != "undefined") {
        m.push(n.main[l.toString()]);
        l++
    }
}
if (GridApp.logging) {
    $.log(m.length + " talks loaded")
}
m = f(m);
m = GridMathFactory.applyGridMath(m);
GridModel.setTalkVOs(m);
d = e(d);
for (l = 0; l < d.length; l++) {
    d[l].talkIdx = l
}
    GridController.onTalksLoadSuccess()
}
```

Here's the code for function `n`:

```
function n() {
if (GridApp.logging) {
    $.log("GridMathFactory.calculateSubColumns()")
}
var B = 0;
var A;
for (var z = 0; z < q.length; z++) {
    var y = columnScale - 1;
    if (t[y] < f.length) {
        A = g(q[z], B)
    }
    B += (A) ? k : k;
    if (GridApp.logging) {
        $.log("Just calculated column " + z + "; Contained 1 ? " + A)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a Fiddle?

Comment: Sadly the JSON I'm using only exists on localhost, so I can't put up a working Fiddle. How about if I just place the whole code there, would that help?

Answer (score 4):

```
if (n.main != "undefined") {
```

should be:

```
if (n.main !== undefined) {
```

or:

```
if (typeof n.main != "undefined") {
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion. The refresh occurs but the whole grid appears blank, no errors though.

Comment: I'm not even going to try to understand the rest of the code. Give your variables meaningful names, don't post minified code here.

Comment: My apologies, I shouldn't have done that. There's just too much code to sift through, just thought maybe I made a syntax error somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out `main` was something that didn't exist in the JSON I was calling. Removed it and now it works as it should.

```
function j(n) {
var m = [],
    l;
if (n != "undefined") {
    l = 0;
    while (typeof n[l.toString()] != "undefined") {
        m.push(n[l.toString()]);
        l++
    }
}
if (GridApp.logging) {
    $.log(m.length + " talks loaded")
}
m = f(m);
m = GridMathFactory.applyGridMath(m);
GridModel.setTalkVOs(m);
d = e(d);
for (l = 0; l < d.length; l++) {
    d[l].talkIdx = l
}
    GridController.onTalksLoadSuccess()
}
```